# Match query with _all option in Nested object does not return results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an index that contains documents of ParentType. ParentType has a list of NestedType objects which are defined as nested in elasticsearch terms. Below you can see the schema of the objects.

```
[ElasticType(Name = "parentType")]
public class ParentType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<NestedType> NestedTypes { get; set; }   
}

[ElasticType(Name = "nestedType")]
public class NestedType
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

The mappings of these types in the index are defined by the below code.

```
 _client.CreateIndex(c => c
   .Index(_indexName)
   .InitializeUsing(_indexSettings)
   .AddMapping<RealPersonSm>(m => m
       .Properties(p => p
           .NestedObject<NestedType>(n => n
                .Name("nestedTypes")
                .MapFromAttributes()
                .IncludeInParent()
                .IncludeInAll())
           .String(s => s
               .Name(rp => rp.Id)
               .IncludeInAll(false)
               .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)))));
```

I want to be able search in all fields of the nested object.

When using a nested query with a multi-match inner query and I specify the nested fields explicitly the expected results are returned.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
       "query": {
            "multi_match": {
               "query": "query terms",
               "fields": [
                 "nestedType.field1",
                 "nestedType.field2"]
            }
      },
      "path": "nestedTypes"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

However, when i used a nested query with match inner query and the "_all" option as field, no result is returned.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
       "query": {
          "match": {
             "_all": "query terms"
          }
      },
      "path": "nestedTypes"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Is there a specific issue with the match query with "_all" fields option when referring to fields of a nested object or am I missing something in the process?

I am using elasticsearch 1.4 and NEST 1.6.1.